# Legality IP collection/storage

Tags: ip, legal, monitoring

Without giving too much away, I'm contemplating on designing a service/app for a specific business to monitor certain static IPs such as their service providers and other statically connected devices (cameras, routers, etc.). An internally underlining set of these statically connected devices are through a VPN router which I can obtain access through from the matching VPN client, while the root of the devices would all be available publicly. The need is too simply ping each device and monitor uptime and potentially latency.

What I'm curious about are what are the legal implications of collecting and storing information such as this? Obviously this is something the customer base would be well informed of.

From a few quick google searches, tools with similar functionality seem to have clients install their software on their remote servers so that they can see it from a web based portal or app, which would avoid the storing of such info I'd assume. Since my service needs are relatively simple, I don't think it is necessary (nor possible with this particular company) to provide such software.

Thoughts?

Gerneio

P.S. Only US clients for the time being.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the correct forum for a legal question. Much of your answer is going to depend on the legal jurisdiction, both yours, and the legal jurisdiction of the service providers.  In addition, the terms and conditions of the services provided may preclude such activities.

Comment: Sorry, I saw other such questions posted here. Any suggestions on other forums?

Comment: You could try https://law.stackexchange.com/ with a proper context of what you intend to do, from where, and for whom I guess.

Comment: IP addresses are like phone numbers, and they are always logged and retained by http logs.

Comment: Maybe you could also have a look to SNMP as your are speaking of devices uptime.